# Javascript not loading on Android

Tags: javascript, android, button

The following code is working on a webpage and also IOS, but not working on Android, why?

It's suppose to generate a webpage inside the app. Is there some language below that is not supported by Android? Thank you!

```
<div id="4b" style="color: #666666; padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
    <span style="font-family: helvetica;">
        <span style="font-family:helvetica;">
            <br />
        </span>
    </span>
    <p>
        <span style="font-family: helvetica; font-size: 40pt;">
            Enter your <b>Invoice Number(s)</b> and <b>Payment Amount</b> below:
        </span>
    </p>
    <form id="form">
        <input id="invoice_number" style="font-size: 35pt; height: 80px; width: 550px;" type="text" placeholder="Invoice Number(s)" required="" value="" name="invoice_no" />
        <input id="payment_amount" style="font-size: 35pt; height: 80px; width: 550px;" type="text" placeholder="Payment Amount" required="" value="" name="payment_amount" />
        <button id="button" style="font-size: 35pt; height: 80px; width: 550px;" type="submit">
            Pay with Credit Card
        </button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    window.open("https://www.payjunction.com/trinity/quickshop/add_to_cart_snap.action?store=paymentbutton&description=INVOICE NO." +
                        $("#invoice_number ").val() +
                        "&need_to_tax=no&need_to_ship=no&price=" +
                        $("#payment_amount").val()
                    );
                });
            });
        </script>
    </form>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: but it's working on IOS, but not in Android.

Comment: you compare IOS and Android - in this context neither of them are a browser